# React Native, Spring REST: image served is not loading on the app

Tags: android, image, react-native, loading, spring-rest

i'm working with React Native to build an Android app. I have a Spring REST backend that serve pictures that were uploaded by app's users.

Here is the code I use to serve the picture:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}/picture", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "image/jpg")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getProfilePictureJpg(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user = userRepository.findOneById(id);
        byte[] imageData;
        String path = user.getPicturePath();
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
            imageData = baos.toByteArray();
            return imageData;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("File not found");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I load an image on a browser, it's working:
[Browser loading picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pa4l.png)

The problem is that when i try with the same url on React, picture is not loading:

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'http://192.168.0.15:8082/user/1/picture'}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}}/>
```

Of course, I tried with another picture, and it works:

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} style={{width: 300, height: 300}}/>
```

I read that iOS needed the image source to be secured with HTTPS, but nothing like that for Android.

Hope someone will be able to help me...
Thanks

Comment: You can maybe try to listen to the `onError` event and see what information you get from there, or the [`prefech`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.40/docs/image.html#prefetch) method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and it seems that `onError` event is not triggered. I also tried the `onLoadStart` and `onLoadEnd` which are both triggered.

Comment: Also, are you trying this on an emulator or phone? Are you sure they are on the same network? Try to open the image URL on the devices' browser.

Comment: I'm trying on the device and i'm sure they're on the same network (all the datas of my app are loading from this rest api). I tried on the device's browser and it worked too. Could this be a format problem ? I tried to encode the picture in base64 format but it didn't work... Thanks for your help

Comment: @Quentin Lerebours I have the same problem, Was this solved?

Comment: Unfortunalely no... It was a personnal project that I paused while i'm stuck. I'm waiting to meet people that have greater knowledge about React that I do, but i'm not sure that this is a problem concerning React itself... 
If you find a solution i'm curious to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

The Android simulator is on a different network than your laptop.

Try running `adb reverse tcp:8082 tcp:8082` in your terminal before building on an Android device. This will redirect your phones port 8082 to your computers port 8082. You can change 8082 to any number that works best for you.